# ConcurrentDictionary in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to use ConcurrentDictionary in my monotouch app. Everything runs OK in the I am trying to use ConcurrentDictionary in my monotouch app. Everything runs OK in the simulator however when I run in an iPad I get the following exception when creating an instance of the class which uses it. Any thoughts?

```
System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Collections.Concurrent.SplitOrderedList`2<string, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string, object>>:.ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1<string>)' while running with --aot-only.

  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]..ctor (IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3444) issue because of [how](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations#Limited_Generics_Support), internally, the class is using generics. You can add yourself to the bug c.c. to get notified of updates / resolution.

Comment: do you know if this still is an issue with the latest xamarin (stable) release?

Comment: All the related test cases we had were all working on stable, so it's very likely that its fixed. OTOH you might want to test with 6.3.x (beta) since that will fix a lot of similar issues you could encounter.

Comment: Very nice, thx for your answer. I'm getting the same impression with my (rather cheap) small test's i wrote... seems like they fixed a lot of issues with the latest beta-release.